Combining Python Selector and asyncio modules
I'm currently implementing a server response handler using the selector module in Python. For sending requests to multiple servers and handling I/O operations, I'm leveraging asyncio.
In my main loop, I add asyncio tasks and let them run for a short period before using selector.select:
if asyncio_tasks:
    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(asyncio_tasks, timeout=0.1)
    asyncio_tasks = list(pending)

next_task_delta = max(self.tasks[0].timestamp - time.time(), 0)
events = self.selector.select(timeout=next_task_delta)
for key, mask in events:
    server = key.data
    server._handle_request_noblock()

My question is whether this approach is considered good practice. If so, I'm curious if there's a more efficient or elegant way to achieve the same outcome. Specifically, I'm concerned about not knowing the optimal duration to wait for tasks before running select.
I've tried different ways for combining them but non of them worked.

you just need to await the tasks. This ensures completion.  You can gather tasks and await the gathered tasks (for multiple tasks).

I'm unsure why you are mixing using selectors with asyncio. Internally asyncio pretty much just uses selectors to achieve its goals, the event loop for asyncio is an extended version of what you have in the second section of your code and already has ways of determining the optimal waiting time. You can see usage of select in the Python source code
